# How to open Google Account Info in android through an intent

Tags: android

Actually I have been facing difficulties in opening the Google Account Info activity through an intent..

So please anyone who knows help me

Thank you for your concern

**Screenshot of the activity I want to open through intent**
[image: Screenshot of the activity I want to open through intent]